# перегрузка операторов в порождаемом классе на основе методов базового класса

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, function-overloading, traits

Вопрос относится к использованию вспомогательного класса свойств (`Traits`) для автоматической генерации некоторых вторичных функций.

Ниже я попытаюсь дать детальное объяснение проблемы и описать концепцию построения моей программы. Сам вопрос начинается с **выделенного жирным текста** практически в самом низу. Поэтому те, кто хочет увидить непосредственно вопрос, могут сразу проследовать вниз поста.

---

Здесь же я попытаюсь объяснить иерархию и причину использования подобной структуры кода. Для лучшего понимания вопроса я буду описывать проблему на примере работы с математическими матрицами.

Имеется некий сложный абстрактный код, который может осуществлять определенные операции с матрицами (диагонализация и т.д.). Абстрактный он в том смысле, что может работать с произвольной реализацией объекта типа `Matrix` через некоторый шаблонный интерфейс (как раз через `Traits`). Определяя для каждого типа матрицы свой интерфейс мы можем очень легко использовать тот же код для диагонализации с различными типами матриц.

К примеру:

```
class MatrixA{
  //конкретная реализация типовых операций с матрицами,
  //со своими публичными членами для вызова
  //например сложение:
  MatrixA sum(const MatrixA& one, const MatrixB& two){...}
};

class MatrixB{
  //совершенно другая реализации матрицы
  //с совершенно другим интерфейсом
  MatrixB do_summation(...){...}
};
```

Есть два совершенно разных по реализации объекта, которые однако несут в себе одинаковую функциональную составляющую.

Используя именно функциональные свойства объектов можно написать алгоритмы максимально абстрагированные от конкретной реализации. К примеру та же диагонализация включает в себя некий набор последовательных операций (сложение матриц, умножение на вектор и т.д.).

В качестве посредника между конкретной реализацией и кодом для диагонализации я использую шаблонный интерфейс:

```
template<typename MatrixType>
class MatrixAlgebra{
  virtual MatrixType matrix_add(const MatrixType& m1,
                                const MatrixType& m2) const=0;
};

template<typename MatrixType, typename MatrixAlgebraType>
class Traits{
  typedef MatrixType matrix_t;
  typedef MatrixAlgebraType matrix_algebra_t;
};
```

который затем применяю для каждого конкретного типа:

```
class AMatrixAlgebra:
public MatrixAlgebra<MatrixA>{
  MatrixA matrix_add(const MatrixA& m1,
                     const MatrixA& m2) const override{
    //реализация с учетом конкретных особенностей типа MatrixA
  }
};

typedef Traits<MatrixA,AMatrixAlgebra> ATraits;
```

и соответственно похожим образом для объекта `MatrixB`.

И затем я могу очень просто применить диагонализацию к этим двум разным объектам:

```
MatrixA mA;
diagonalize<ATraits>(mA);

//и точно так же
MatrixB mB(...);//может быть совершенно другой конструктор
diagonalize<BTraits>(mB);
```

Все это работает правильно.

Извиняюсь за столь долгое введение, написал его для объяснения причин использования такого "громоздкого" интерфейса, дабы исключить очевидные ответы, которые совершенно не будут вписываться в приведенную выше концепцию.

---

**Итак, непосредственно вопрос:**

Как с помощью шаблонного класса свойств можно породить операции перегрузки операторов, в частности оператора `+`?

Вопрос состоит именно в перегрузке операторов, поскольку в данном случае (без непосредственного доступа к объекту типа `Matrix`) приходиться пользоваться `friend` определением.

К примеру, следующий код работает правильно:

```
template<typename Traits>
class AutoGenerator:
public Traits::matrix_algebra_t{
  typedef typename Traits::matrix_t matrix_t;
  typedef typename Traits::matrix_algebra_t matrix_algebra_t;
public:
  AutoGenerator(){}
  matrix_t some_action(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2){
    //и к примеру где-то тут делается сложение
    matrix_algebra_t::matrix_add(m1,m2);
  }
};
```

Есть какой-то вспомогательный класс, которые генерирует требуемые функции исходя из знания базовых операций, опеределенных в интерфейсе.

Однако при попытке генерировать таким образом перегрузку операторов:

```
template<typename Traits>
class AutoGenerator:
public Traits::matrix_algebra_t{
  typedef typename Traits::matrix_t matrix_t;
  typedef typename Traits::matrix_algebra_t matrix_algebra_t;
public:
  AutoGenerator(){}
  friend matrix_t operator+(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2){
    //и к примеру где-то тут делается сложение
    return matrix_algebra_t::matrix_add(m1,m2);
  }
};
```

возникает ошибка компилятора: `error: cannot call member function "...::matrix_add" without object`. Определенный как `friend` оператор не работает.

Как можно обойти эту проблему?

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь и извиняюсь за длинное изложение!

PS: К проблеме не относится, но будет интересно выслушать ваше мнение по поводу подобной организации кода. Возможно существуют какие-то более изящные парадигмы для реализации асбтрактных интерфейсов.

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод `matrix_add` - метод экземпляра, а вы его пытаетесь вызвать как статический.

Вы или экземпляр класса `matrix_algebra_t` создайте - или метод статическим сделайте.